# player.stop() dosen 't works on videojs

Tags: javascript, html5-video, video.js

I'm trying to implement videojs with the IMA plugin, and i need to capture the stop and play event from a button outside the videobox in my react app.
The thing is i capture the event on my buttons and works fine, but they dosen t work when i want to stop the ADS.. why? Any clue? 
i use this example

```
https://googleads.github.io/videojs-ima/examples/simple/
```

and i log the player.ima and return this, but i cant access to any element..

[image]

here is my code! thanks!

index.js

```
<video id="content_video" 
  class="video-js vjs-default-skin"" 
  controls 
>
<source src="//commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4" ></source>
</video> 

<script>

window.player = videojs

var player =  window.player('content_video');

var options = {
    id: 'content_video',
    adTagUrl: 'http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?sz=640x480&iu=/124319096/external/ad_rule_samples&ciu_szs=300x250&ad_rule=1&impl=s&gdfp_req=1&env=vp&output=xml_vmap1&unviewed_position_start=1&cust_params=sample_ar%3Dpremidpostpod%26deployment%3Dgmf-js&cmsid=496&vid=short_onecue&correlator='
  };

  player.ima(options);


</script>
```

home.js

```
  handlePlay = () => {
        if(this.props.showPlay == 'block'){
            const player = window.videojs(`#content_video`)
            player.play() //only work on the video not in ads

        } else {
            const player = window.videojs(`#content_video`)
            player.pause() //only work on the video not in ads
        }
   }
```